# En la pestaña SDK tools no me aparece la opción de Android Sdk tools

Tags: android-studio, programación-móvil, sdk

Buen día, alguien me podría ayudar con el SDK Tools. En esta pestaña no me aparece la opción Android Sdk tools, solo me aparece el Android SDK Platform-tools y Android Emulator. Pero no me aparece el **Android SDK tools.** que puedo hacer para habilitar esa opción
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La opción "Android SDK Tools" se va a mostrar siempre y cuando tengas un Android SDK válido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegurate de definir la ruta correcta de tu Android SDK, ve a SDK Platforms, define la ruta de tu Android SDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En las nuevas versiones de android studio ya no aparece Tools>SDK Manager.

Primero instalar el Java Development Kit (JDK) desde la web de oracle.

En android studio ir a File>Settings>Appereance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK>SDK Tools y ahí instalar el USB driver y lo que podamos necesitar.